# How do I specify ffmpeg video directory?

Tags: macos, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I'm sure this is a very basic question so I apologise but I couldn't find it being asked on here before.

I've just downloaded and installed ffmpeg for Mac OSX and the main thing I want to use it for is converting files like AVIs or MP4s into MOVs or reducing the frame rate or resolution.

I have a video in a folder in my movies folder called test.mp4 but when I try to use ffmpeg to convert it by typing 'ffmpeg -i test.mp4 test.avi' it keeps telling me 'No such file or directory' it does the same thing when I try it with other videos. The videos are definitely there though.

So is there a specific folder I need to put the videos into, like an input directory or is there a way in the command line that I can specify the folder the video is in?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## You can tell ffmpeg where to look for files

If you are launching `ffmpeg from the terminal, you will need to either change directory to the location of the video you would like to work on, or specify the full path.

### Getting the file location

> I have a video in a folder in my movies folder called test.mp4 but when I try to use ffmpeg to convert it by typing 'ffmpeg -i test.mp4 test.avi' it keeps telling me 'No such file or directory' it does the same thing when I try it with other videos. The videos are definitely there though.

If Finder, you can hit <kbd>Cmd+C</kbd> on the directory you have your movies in, as if you were going to copy it. You can then hit <kbd>Cmd+V</kbd> in the terminal to paste that directory's **path** (where it is found on your Mac).

Then use the `cd` command to change to that directory:

```
cd /Users/Arron/Movies/
```

and redo your ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 test.avi
```

Alternatively, you could specify the full path to *both* the input and output files:

```
ffmpeg -i /Users/Arron/Movies/test.mp4 /Users/Arron/Movies/test.avi
```

It would be worth reading up on the [ffmpeg documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/) to learn about what the command you are doing does, as it may not be what you expect.

Comment: Amazing, thank you for that, now I've told it where to look it's worked straight away. I'll look through the documentation as well though like you say just to make sure I understand what's actually being done. Thanks!

Comment: @bertieb The user can't upvote answers due to the lack of reputation.

Comment: @slhck Oh, I thought you could always comment/vote on As to your own Qs; good to know!

Comment: +1 Do either of you know how to fix EXT-X-MAP:URI in m3u8 when specifying absolute hls_fmp4_init_filename using ffmpeg? Using absolute directory like you suggested isn't working. https://stackoverflow.com/q/60460212/470749 Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you open a terminal and you're referring to a file name, the shell looks for the file relative to your [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory).

To see your working directory, enter:

```
pwd
```

To change to another working directory, enter `cd`. So if your file is in the folder `~/Downloads/videos`, run:

```
cd ~/Downloads/videos/
```

You can also drag the file from your Finder to the terminal, that is, if you type:

```
ffmpeg -i __
          ^---- your cursor is here
```

Then you can drag and drop the file to where your cursor is, and it will automatically add the full path to the file.

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply, I'm now specifying the full file directory for now but it's good to know how to change the working directory when I need to. thanks!